# c++ error when converting from hex string to int

Tags: c++, string, hex, stdvector

I am writing a program that accepts a text file of hex values. I store these hex values in a `vector<string>` and then use `stol` to convert the hex string to an integer then I store that in a new `vector<int>`.

```
vector<string> flir_times;
vector<int> flir_dec;

for(int i = 0; i < flir_times.size() ; i++){
    int x = stol(flir_times[i], nullptr, 16);
    flir_dec.push_back(x);
    cout << flir_dec[i] << endl;
}
```

The program was originally working; but today for some reason it doesn't seem to be converting some new hex values correctly. Here is a short snippet of the hex values that need to be converted:

[image]

These are the values that the program should be converting them to:

[image]

However when I run my program it converts the hex values into large negative numbers then it crashes. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the program to not convert the hex numbers correctly then crash?

Comment: If it used to work, are you sure that the input file has the same syntax as before?

Comment: yes, earlier on in the code I get the user to input the text file directory, so I'm positive that the file is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program continues to work correctly, it's just that the added hex numbers that you are trying to read are representations of negative 32-bit integers. For example, the most significant byte of `A4B844A2` is `10100100`. It has `1` in the most significant "sign" bit, so the number is actually negative.

Switch to unsigned numbers, and use [`std::stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) to parse input to fix this problem:

```
vector<string> flir_times;
vector<unsigned> flir_dec;

for(int i = 0; i < flir_times.size() ; i++){
    unsigned x = stoul(flir_times[i], nullptr, 16);
    flir_dec.push_back(x);
    cout << flir_dec[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: @TobySpeight You are right, `std::stoul` is more appropriate. I forgot its name, and didn't find it on the reference page for `std::stol`. Oddly, cppreference placed unsigned functions on a separate page. Thank you very much!